# 64 bit Unsigned Hash Function

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have 64-bit unsigned integers (ranging from 0 to 2^63 - 1) and I want to hash them into 32-bit unsigned integers (0 to 2^31 - 1 range).

Data follows [Uniform Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29). Can anyone suggest a hash function that will give a low number of collisions for this distribution (may be with some probability of collision occurrence)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the distribution of the is really uniform, then just take the lower `n` bits (the width of the hash value). This would mean, that worst case you can have 2<sup>N-n</sup> elements in a bucket. (here `N` denotes the width of the original number)

**Note:** just saw @JanDvorak already suggested this (before my answer), using modulo 2<sup>n</sup> is equivalent to taking the lower `n` bits...

If this is really about **64 bit unsigned integers** being hashed into **32 bit unsigned integers**, then the correct ranges would be **[0;2<sup>64</sup>-1]** and **[0;2<sup>32</sup>-1]**, with at most **2<sup>32</sup>** collisions on a single hash. However, in Java, there is no unsigned integer...

If this is about using the positive half of signed 64 and 32 bit integer values respectively, then your range values are right, and you will still have **2<sup>32</sup>** collisions worst case.

Comment: @JanDvorak: there is a confusion in the spec: `32bit unsigned integer` vs `2^31-1`. Even though that is true that in Java, there is no unsigned Integer... I'll detail this a bit in the answer

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple distribution, any sensible hash function would fit. To make sure, just try `(int)(longvalue+(longvalue>>32))` and count collisions. If you want only 31 bit, make `res&0x7fffffff` (why do you stress values are unsigned? 31 bit int and 63 bit long fit into both signed and unsigned ranges).

Comment: The desired range is 0..(2^31-1)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you hashing if you already have the right length and uniform distribution of bits? I assume you have some security requirement in mind? Please share.

If it's a standard hash you are looking for, consider SHA-1:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
//Some more imports

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
md.update(data);
byte[] hash = md.digest());
```

Comment: One thing I thought about is that the data might be sparse, and storing all the 64 bits would be overkill, and probably hashing them to 32 bit would mean lower memory footprint, and even for 32 bit infrastructures, lower performance impact...

Comment: Well, SHA-1 outputs 160bit. Also, it's many times more complex than the other answers you are getting, so you should certainly not go this route if security is not a requirement